# WCF Async call that return void and is OneWay

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, iasyncresult

I use WCF to async communicate between 2 processes.
till now I implemented the IAsyncResult pattern, and did it by having 3 methods:
BeginOperation - client.BeginOperation, when service receive it queue the job on threadpool with delegate for Operation
Operation - run on service side
EndOperation - this is what client callback.

My question is, I want to send strings from client to service, I want the send to be async, AND I dont want to get response - just want the service to print the string.
Is this enough ? This must be **Non-Blocking**

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void PrintString(string message);
```

OR i need to do as following:

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern=true)]
    void BeginPrintString(string message, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndPrintString(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IsOneWay should be enough, but it still can **block** your client in specific circumstances, as well as **throw errors.**

See [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/zuker/archive/2009/01/24/wcf-and-oneway-operations-is-oneway-really-oneway.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/zuker/archive/2009/01/26/wcf-and-oneway-behavioral-inconsistency.aspx) posts for more details:

> General things you should keep in mind about OneWay operations -
>
> O/W operations must return void. O/W operations can still yield
>   exceptions. invoking an operation on the client channel might still
>   throw an exception if it couldn’t transmit the call over to the
>   service. O/W operations can still block. if the service is pumped with
>   messages and a queue had started, calling O/W operation may block your
>   following code.

Comment: how IsOneWay is enough if they write explicitly that: O/W operations can still block. if the service is pumped with messages and a queue had started, calling O/W operation may block your following code.

Comment: Its depends on your usage / needs. For example, if you call server once per hour, and you sat throttling to 100 concurrent  calls, ... I'd consider to review  configuration and Use Case (yes, still can happen) to measure possibility of blocked / waiting client.

Comment: this is my logging service, meaning that 5-10 different processes will  do their logging using client calls. each process have wcf client that send string message to log. the service will then log the string. constant logging from multiple clients and the Service is Single

Comment: Ok, all I mean is may be for your service IsOneWay will be good enough. You can also consider to use wcf + MSMQ binding

Answer (score -1):

You can make it more asynchronous by using a separate thread to do your work.

Instead of:

```
public void MyOneWayServiceOperation() {
   // do stuff
}
```

do something like:

```
public void MyOneWayServiceOperation() {
   new Thread(() => {
      // do stuff
   }).Start();
}
```

The service operation will have been executed on a new thread anyway, so it shouldn't cause any more problems for your code to be on a different new thread.

You can add a `Thread.Sleep()` call before your work if you want the service operation to have completed before you begin. This allowed me to quit the service from a service operation without having an exception thrown.